# getIdentities spends a lot of time

Tags: performance, magento2.3.2

We have very slow product detail pages.

In a blackfire trace I see, that a lot of time is spent in getIdentities.

Did anybody see this before? [image]

If I `return [];` in \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct::getIdentities product pages which are not in FPC are down from 6-15 seconds to 900 ms on my dev machine.

Edit: I was giving that link on Twitter

https://youtu.be/PyDC9_dKZq8 at 50:15

Comment: I have a few questions:
1. Why you have a lot of ListProduct blocks in your PDP?
2. Did you disable all of the caches while profiling the page?

Comment: Profiling is with FPC empty for that page but all caches on. We have some related product blocks.

Comment: Do you have a lot of product attributes? As I can see the ProductCollection::_loadAttributes takes most of the time in method getIdentities

Comment: @ToanTam It would guess around 50... They might be all on use in list, which is unfortunate. Still it's strange

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that the problem is caused by

```
$productBlockObj= $block->getLayout()->createBlock('Example\ProductListings\Block\Product\ListProduct')
```

in a custom `items.phtml`

This seems to cause `getIdentities()` to work wit un-loaded product collections.

Moving the logic of that block to a view model solves the problem.

`getIdentities` is still called, but takes much less time.

So it is more developer experience problem than a core bug.

Others with a similar issue could have a look at the production collection  in `getIdentities` and check if it is already loaded or not.